# mysql_client failing on ubuntu 18.04 to install Chef 12.13.37

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops, aws-opsworks

I am using aws / opsworks with a running setup using ubuntu 16.04 and chef 12.13.37 which works fine, 16.04 is now end of life. so we are going to upgrade to 18.04 although mysql_client doesn't seem to install with the following errors

```
INFO: Processing mysql_client_installation_package[default] action create (vd_mysql::default line 8)
[2021-05-05T06:01:27+00:00] WARN: Default value nil is invalid for property version of resource . Possible fixes: 1. Remove 'default: nil' if nil means 'undefined'. 2. Set a valid default value if there is a reasonable one. 3. Allow nil as a valid value of your property (for example, 'property :version, [ String, nil ], default: nil'). Error: Property version must be one of: String!  You passed nil. (CHEF-5)/var/chef/runs/fe0f771f-e6da-44b2-903f-fcfd66f6dd92/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_base.rb:26:in `block in <class:MysqlBase>'.
Please see https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_custom_resource_cleanups.html for further details and information on how to correct this problem. at /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/event_dispatch/dispatcher.rb:43:in `call'
 
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_client_installation_package[default]'
================================================================================
 
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

the command it is trying to run is.

```
mysql_client 'default' do
   action :create
end
```

Comment: did you try to update mysql cookbok version?

Comment: I hadn't tried to update the mysql cookbook version.